# Big column including different rows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to improve the view of a web and I want to classify some objects.

My idea is to classify by course, later by quarter and later the subject.

In this photo I'm trying to do 2 levels (course+subject) and I want to have all the subjects of the first course like the first one (SAE).

[image]

SAE2 is in a bad place and I don't know how to put it below SAE.

I'm using Bootstrap but I have some CSS. Here is my code:

```css
.columnaCurs{
    height:200px;
    width:50%;
    color:White;
    text-align:center;
    
}
.verticalText{
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    padding-top:100%;
}
.curs1{
    background-color:Blue;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-md-1 align-self-center"><div class="columnaCurs curs1"><span class="verticalText">1st course</span></div></div>
      <div class="col col-md-8 card" style="height:25%;">SAE</div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-md-8 card" style="height:25%;">SAE2</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

How can I improve it? Later I'll add better design but I want to have this "draw" of levels.

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your bootstrap columns and row  I have added updated solution

```css
.columnaCurs{
    height:200px;
    width:50%;
    color:White;
    text-align:center;
    
}
.verticalText{
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    padding-top:100%;
}
.curs1{
    background-color:Blue;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <div class="col align-self-center"><div class="columnaCurs curs1"><span class="verticalText">1st course</span></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card" style="">SAE</div>
          </div>
           <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card" style="">SAE2</div>
           </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's better than mine, but I'm seeing it https://i.imgur.com/BS0mcP8.png and I want something like that: https://i.imgur.com/DsPhaLM.png